# nano freezes on django deploy git pull

Tags: django, git, deployment, nano

I followed these instructions for writing a deploy script with fabric http://www.yaconiello.com/blog/deploying-django-site-fabric/

THe problem is that when it does the 'git pull origin master' through ssh it tries to open nano and ask me to save the commit message that says 'Merging master branch blah blah...'

If I try to 'ctrl-o' in nano like I usually do, nano becomes unresponsive and I have to 'ctrl-c' the whole thing. It works if I go into a sperate ssh, do the git pull manually and then run the script again, but that sort of beats the point of having the deploy script do it automatically in the first place. I am stumped about how to get around that step or make nano work under those conditions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add --no-edit to the pull. vim and nano both left the terminal unresponsive.

Fabric file...

```
def fabfoo():
    run('git pull --no-edit origin master')
```